# Чем отличается List от ArrayList?

Tags: java

Чем отличается `List` от `ArrayList`. Погуглил, но толком ничего не нашел (как минимум, на русском языке). Насколько я понял, `ArrayList` является реализацией `List`, однако различий я особых не заметил. Так в чем же все-таки разница?

Comment: Дык `List` - это интерфейс....`ArrayList ` его реализует....

Comment: У интерфейса List может быть несколько реализаций. Одна из них - ArrayList. Но есть еще AbstractList, AbstractSequentialList, LinkedList, AttributeList, RoleList, RoleUnresolvedList, CopyOnWriteArrayList, LinkedList

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Так как `ArrayList` реализует интерфейс `List`, то у него должны быть все методы `List` плюс (возможно) какие-то другие.  Отсюда внешняя схожесть. 
При этом в `List` эти методы вообще никак не реализованы и невозможно создать объект командой `new List()`.

Реализации одного и того же интерфейса могут иметь внешне одни и те же методы, но радикально отличаться их внутренней реализацией. Например, в основе `ArrayList` - массив, который при необходимости заменяется большим (или меньшим) по размеру с переписыванием содержимого из старого в новый. В основе же `LinkedList` (другой реализации интерфейса `List`) лежит двунаправленный связанный список, а каждый элемент списка содержит в себе ссылку на следующий и предыдущий элементы.

Answer (score 8):

> То есть рекомендуется писать так как вы указали, вместо `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`? А почему рекомендуется писать именно так? Есть ли в этом различие?

В ссылку типа `List` вы можете присвоить объект любого наследующего его типа (и `ArrayList` и `LinkedList`). Потом можете вызывать из этой ссылки методы, которые есть в типе `List`, не задумываясь, какой именно объект вы туда поместили.

Например, так удобно передавать параметры в методы или создавать массивы объектов `List`, которые могут содержать объекты разных типов в разных элементах.

Answer (score 2):

Как правило к `List` "приводят" объект нужного класса, реализующего интерфейс `List`.

К примеру, насколько я знаю, рекомендуется писать именно

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

и т.д.

Comment: то есть рекомендуется писать так как вы указали, вместо `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` ? А почему рекомендуется писать именно так? Есть ли в этом различие?