# Зачем указывают тип List при создании ArrayList

Tags: java

Есть запись:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Зачем указывать тип `List`, а не `ArrayList`? Часто встречаю в туториалах такой вид записи, но нигде не объясняли зачем это нужно.

Т.е в чем различие записи:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

от

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Буду рад получить ссылку на статью где освещается эта тема.

Comment: List это не предок, а интерфейс - он объеденяет все типы коллекций и в последствии вы можете использовать другой тип коллекции без существенных изменений кода или вызывать методы коллекций не вдаваясь в то, какого именно они типа. Вопрос [по теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505307/177345)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/600330/220996

Comment: прочитал, но все равно не понял. Может есть какая-то статья где подробно и с примерами объясняется?

Comment: @ВиталийБелоусов, Effective Java, item 52.