# В чем отличие при создании экземпляра ArrayList?

Tags: java

В чем разница методов написания кода:

1. Через интерфейс `List`:

   ```
   List<Integer> name = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ```
2. Через класс `ArrayList`:

   ```
   ArrayList<Integer> name = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличается List от ArrayList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505307/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-list-%d0%be%d1%82-arraylist)

Comment: @dmtr, там вот именно на этот вопрос и не ответили

Comment: @dmtr, в топике я писал `List<Integer> name = new ArrayList<Integer>();`

Comment: @dmtr, в топике написано `List<Integer> name = new ArrayList<Integer>();` - видно, когда правлю сообщение, а показывается в итоге после сохранения так, как показывается

Comment: Создание именно тут происходит `new ArrayList<Integer>()`, а `List<Integer> name = ` и `ArrayList<Integer> name = ` уже создание переменной, куда ссылка на объект будет положена, т.е. это инициализация. В обоих случаях будет объект ArrayList, но `List` является общим типом и в него можно положить и другие объекты, что реализуют `List`, а не только `ArrayList`. Читайте: [Чем отличается List от ArrayList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505307/)

Comment: вот это `List<Integer> name` - переменная, то есть, грубо говоря, коробка с надписью `место для List<Integer> name`, вот тут `name = new ArrayList<Integer>();` вы помещаете в эту коробку `ArrayList<Integer>();`. Ваши примеры отличаются только надписями на коробке, содержимое же  коробок там одинаковое.

Comment: Поиск по запросу "List ArrayList" выдал четыре с лишним сотни результатов, из которых не меньше четверти - дубликаты этого вопроса. А ведь ещё есть "Map HashMap"! Надо уже выбрать среди них каноничный и беспощадно клеить...

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev я бы склеил, но искать лень :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ок, если не ответили по ссылке в комментарии, тогда постараюсь простыми словами (?).

Полиморфизм - возможность иметь несколько форм реализаций, но какую конкретно форму реализации интерфейса (в вашем случае `List`) использовать именно сейчас, вы указываете справа от оператора `new` - `ArrayList`.

Возьмем для сравнения пару часто сравниваемых классов - это `ArrayList` и `LinkedList`. Они имеют много общих методов, т.к. оба реализуют интерфейс `List`.

Например, у вас есть метод, который перебирает элементы в списке, производит какие-то действия внутри.

Когда вы проектировали ваше приложение, вы работали с `LinkedList`, но на больших данных заметили, что скорость прохождения по списку упала (такое бывает, но не точно) и решили перейти на `ArrayList`.

Ваш метод был и остается всегда:

```
public void sortList(List<Integer> list) {
    // your code...
}
```

Таким образом инициализацию списка мы можете менять в одном месте, вам не придется менять ее везде.

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
```

просто меняете на:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Вот `преимущество` данного метода я заметил в аргументе метода, а именно, что можно указать `List<Integer>` и туда паредавать `ArrayList<Integer>` либо `LinkedList<Integer>`. Но если мне требуется создать просто единожды `ArrayList`, то принципиального различия в методах - 1) `List<Integer> name = new ArrayList<>();` и 2) `ArrayList<Integer> name = new ArrayList<>();`  нету, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @n199a принципиального нет