# Вопрос по реализации List и ArrayList

Tags: java, массивы, list, arraylist, динамические-массивы

В каких случаях лучше использовать

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

а в каких

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличается List от ArrayList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505307/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-list-%d0%be%d1%82-arraylist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` — это интерфейс. `ArrayList` реализует интерфейс `List`.

Если вы пишете

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

вам будут доступны в том числе методы, специфичные для [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). Например, [ensureCapacity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int)).

Если вы захотите поменять `ArrayList` на другую реализацию интерфейса, вам нужно будет отказываться от используемых методов, которые предоставляет `ArrayList`, но не предоставляет новая реализация.

Если вы пишете

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

вам будут доступны только методы из интерфейса [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Вариант `List` обычно более предпочтителен, т.к. позволяет вам не привязываться к конкретной реализации интерфейса. Вы сможете легко заменить одну реализацию на другую, просто поменяв имя класса в конструкторе.

Answer (score 1):

Следуя всем канонам дизайна классов и написания кода `ArrayList list = new ArrayList` следует применять в лучше случае **никогда**. 
Коммуникация между классам, в том числе и коллекциями должна происходить всегда только через их интерфейсы, что так же дает вам возможность уйти от `hard coupling` в коде и писать менее реализация-зависимых кусков кода.