# Интерфейсы и экземпляры класса в java

Tags: java

Всем привет! Начинаю изучать java и никак не могу до конца понять такой момент:

Скажем у меня есть интерфейс Iter1, так же есть класс, который имплементирует данный интерфейс Class1.

Я могу создать экземпляр класса  Class1 class = new Class(); или же Iter1 class = new Class();

Эти записи будут равнозначны? и если нет, то в чем их принципиальное отличие?

Заранее спасибо за пояснение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Чем отличается List от ArrayList?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/505307/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-list-%d0%be%d1%82-arraylist)

Comment: Я думаю сойдёт.

Comment: Спасибо, почитал эту статью, но возник еще вопрос.

Цитата :"В ссылку типа List вы можете присвоить объект любого наследующего его типа (и ArrayList и LinkedList). Потом можете вызывать из этой ссылки методы, которые есть в типе List, не задумываясь, какой именно объект вы туда поместили."

"Так как ArrayList реализует интерфейс List, то у него должны быть все методы List плюс (возможно) какие-то другие. "

Зачем тогда писать List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();, если мы сможем вызывать только методы из интерфейса List? В этом есть какой то смысл?

Comment: смысл в том, что называется в ооп полиморфизм

Comment: О полиморфизме можно немного почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/935433/204920). Там также сказано зачем мы используем интерфейсы при программировании на Java.

Comment: Большое спасибо!