# Интерфейсная переменная

Tags: java, ооп, коллекции

Во многих примерах кода объявляется ссылочная переменная интерфейса, которая ссылается на объект класса реализующий этот интерфейс. К примеру:

```
List <String> StringCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Каковы преимущества такого подхода в сравнении с присваиванию ссылочной переменной тому классу, который этот же объект и реализует? Т.е. :

```
ArrayList <String> StringCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: и ещё https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/505307/191482  ... и ещё что-то попоиску найти можно  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+List+ArrayList

Comment: Я не имел в виду конкретно List, я использовал его исключительно в качестве примера. Ведь если ссылаться на интерфейс, то будут доступны только методы этого интерфейса. Мне интересен смысл такого подхода. То, что вы скинули выше, я читал. Просто надеялся получить более общий, развернутый ответ.

Comment: Там написан именно смысл такого подхода. Как минимум смысл тот же и его можно экстраполировать на аналогичные вещи

Comment: смысл подхода - полиморфизм например и возможность его использования, особенно в **L**  из so**L**id. Но вроде в дубликатах вполне написано про смысл

Comment: В общем то интерфейс это тип без реализации, который является абстракцией. Что такое абстракция в программировании можно почитать [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818624/204920).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему мы используем интерфейсы при объявлении переменной, потому что мы хотим абстрагироваться от конкретной реализации данного интерфейса. Методы интерфейса все чисто виртуальные и поэтому можно использовать полиморфизм. То есть кодирование с помощью интерфейсов позволяет внедрять нежесткую  связь между классами. Вы можете в любой момент подменить реализацию и в вашем коде не нужно будет делать изменений.

То, что касается интерфейса `List` и его реализации `ArrayList`, то это одна из популярных коллекций, наиболее часто встречающаяся в коде. Если используется только одна реализация и в будущем никто не собирается ее менять, то можно использовать `ArrayList` типом переменной. Тогда вы точно будете знать класс используемой переменной.